# Purpose of this hot water boiler pipe?

Tags: plumbing, boiler

The flow of hot water in all my taps was reduced to a trickle. My thought was that there was sediment build up and the electric boiler needed to be flushed out.

The plumber quickly removed a connecting pipe and all seems well again.

Can anyone confirm what this pipe is (in image attached) and if it's necessary? The bendy pipe was previously attached to the right of this pipe, which was attached to the wall. The bendy pipe now goes directly into the wall (as shown in the photo), bypassing the removed pipe.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The bendy pipe now goes directly into the wall (as shown in the photo), bypassing the removed pipe. I really just wondered if the removed pipe (that I'm holding in the photo) actually does anything, or is it just a connector.

Comment: Definitely not "...just a connector."

Comment: @sa78, please [edit] your additional info into your question, don't put it down here in the comments. Not everyone reads comments and comments can get deleted by a moderator, loosing valuable info.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

The big silver item in the removed section of pipe appears to be a pressure regulator that's been bypassed now. Perhaps it failed.

Not sure why you'd have a pressure regulator just there.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, it's a pressure regulator

Answer (score 0):

The arrow on the removed silver piece indicates that it might be a check valve, allowing water to move from left-to-right (as held in the picture), but not right-to-left.

Removing it is OK, because at the other end of the flexible line (or "bendy pipe"), is another piece with another arrow pointing the same direction. I presume that this, too, is a check valve (operating in the same direction), thus making the removed one redundant.

If the check valve in hand failed, clogged, or was otherwise damaged, removing it was the right thing to do. Since there appeared to be 2 check valves in series with nothing but piping between them, not replacing it has zero net impact on the plumbing system.